# How's the best way to perform a nested concatMap to achieve joining multiple tables?

Tags: join, rethinkdb, concatmap

on the concatMap api page in RethinkDB website, it's saying eqJoin is implemented with concatMap + getAll, which should provide better performance than other joins.

in my case, I'd like to join multiple tables, here's an example, let's assume I have 3 tables, `users`, `departments` and `companies`. in every `user` document would contain a `department id` and `company id`. eg:

```
var user = {
  name: 'Peter',
  company: '12345',
  department: '8888',
  otherDetails: 'abc 123'
}
```

the result I'd like to get after the join query is very similar to the result of a concatMap/eqJoin, but with all 3 tables:

```
[{
  user: {...},
  company: {...},
  department: {...}
}, ...]
```

here is a query I've written that could get the result:

```
r.table('users')
  .concatMap(function(user) {
    return r.table("companies").getAll(
      user("company")
    ).map(function(company) {
      return { user: user, company: company }
    })
  })
  .concatMap(function(row) {
    return r.table("departments").getAll(
      row("user")("department")
    ).map(function(department) {
      return { user: row("user"), company: row("company"), department: department }
    })
  })
```

my questions:

1. is there a better way to do this?
2. is the performance of the above query still as good as usual eqJoin on 2 tables?
3. is the performance of using merge much worse than using eqJoin (concatMap) in these cases?

thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That looks like the best way to do it to me.  If you wanted you could move the second `concatMap` into the first `.concatMap` (so you chain it onto the end of `getAll`).  That might be faster, you'd have to benchmark it to find out, but it should be roughly the same speed.
2. Yes, it should be.
3. I don't think you can do this task with merge.  Any time you want to turn one input row into multiple output rows you need to use `concatMap` or a join.  If instead of one output document per user/company/department pair you want one output document per user with arrays of companies and departments in them, then `merge` could be used for that and should be roughly the same speed (or if anything a tiny bit faster).

Comment: thanks a lot Michael!! // 1. i'm moving `concatMap`s together cos it would be shorter (one `map` only) and more consistent to me (vars inside the `map`) // 2. perfect!! // 3. i got what you mean, `concatMap` is returning exactly what i need for this case now. gonna read more stuffs about `merge` vs `concatMap` in RethinkDB, and think clear about what i have to do before seeking help again. // thanks so much again for the quick answer!! :)